# Copying a linked list into another linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am writing a function that will take an already created linked list and copy that linked list into another linked list. This is what I have so far

```
/* defined types:
   AirportCode is an alias for a 4-char array
   Node is a linked list node (struct) for AirportCodes */
typedef char AirportCode[4];
typedef struct node {
    AirportCode airport;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *copy(Node *list) {
/* REPLACE THIS NON-SOLUTION */
struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->airport = list->airport;
temp->next = copy(list->next);
return(temp);

return NULL;
}

 /* test copy, and print the copy */
    list3 = copy(list1);
    printf("list3 copied from list1: "); printList(list3);
```

When I try to compile this using gcc I get the error:

```
airports.c:50:19: error: array type 'AirportCode' (aka 'char [4]') is not
      assignable
    temp->airport = list->airport;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `memcpy(temp->airport, list->airport, sizeof(AirportCode))`

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is the one the compiler is reporting: you cannot copy the contents of an array of char just assigning one to another. In case it would work, it would assign a pointer to the first position of the array to the other one, which is not what you want.

You must copy the contents of the array position by position, with either:

```
strcpy( temp->airport, list->airport );
```

(provided you can add a zero at the end of each airport code, being `AirportCode` an array of 5, which on the other hand would waste a lot of space), or better with:

```
memcpy(temp->airport, list->airport, sizeof(AirportCode))
```

Anyway, this is not going to solve the actual issue: your are not copying the list in your function `copy()`. I'd rename that function to `copyNode()`:

```
Node *copyNode(Node *list)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->airport = list->airport;
    temp->next = copy(list->next);
    return(temp);
}
```

Now, you are able to create a true function copy:

```
Node *copy(Node *list)
{
    Node * toret = NULL;
    Node * ptrList = list;

    while( ptrList != NULL ) {
        if ( toret == NULL ) {
            toret = copyNode( ptrList );
        } else {
            toret->next = copyNode( ptrList );
            toret = toret->next;
        }

        ptrList = ptrList->next;
    }

    return toret;
}
```

Note that your list should end with a NULL as the next pointer at the last node.

Hope this helps.